# PyQt5: How to place a QPixmap on top of another QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpixmap

I would like to place a QPixmap on another QPixmap. Both have the same size, so I would just like to make an overlay. The overlay image has a transparent elipse in the middle. I figure they should be QPixmap format, however I dont know how to place them on top of each other and keep them in place when resizing the window. This is my code displaying how my background images are placed. I have attached a image explaining what i want.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui ,QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
class Ergolab(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ergolab, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Load the UI Page
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui",self)

        self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap('C:/Users/Frede/Desktop/img1.jpg')
        self.shoflexLLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap1.scaled(self.shoflexLLabel.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.shoflexLLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.shoflexLLabel.setMinimumSize(150, 150) 
        self.shoflexLLabel.resize(800, 600)

        self.pixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap('C:/Users/Frede/Desktop/img2.jpg')
        self.shoflexRLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap2.scaled(self.shoflexRLabel.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.shoflexRLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.shoflexRLabel.setMinimumSize(150, 150) 
        self.shoflexRLabel.resize(800, 600)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        scaledSize = self.shoflexLLabel.size()                       
        if not self.shoflexLLabel.pixmap() or scaledSize != self.shoflexLLabel.pixmap().size():
            self.updateLabel()    

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.shoflexLLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap1.scaled(        
                self.shoflexLLabel.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                Qt.SmoothTransformation))     
        self.shoflexRLabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap2.scaled(        
                self.shoflexRLabel.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                Qt.SmoothTransformation))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Ergolab()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':         
    main()
```

This is the result I would like:
[image]

Comment: I don't remember the API, but what I would to is to attach a QPainter and then blit one onto the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use QPainter by setting the circle as a clip path:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        base_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("background.png")

        overlay_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("overlay.png")

        radius = 300

        r = QtCore.QRectF()
        r.setSize(radius * QtCore.QSizeF(1, 1))
        r.moveCenter(base_pixmap.rect().center())
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(r)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(base_pixmap)
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform
        )
        painter.setClipPath(path, QtCore.Qt.IntersectClip)
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), overlay_pixmap)
        painter.end()

        label.setPixmap(base_pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
[image]

[image]